# Tableau - set filter based on another filter, but don't apply first filter

Tags: sql, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I'm building a story with three dashboards and it's intended as a single-user view, with an "email" parameter used to identify the user.

Based on the email input, two dashboards use a calculated field as a parameter based on "email" but the third is trickier. It needs to show an average calculation for all users with the same "level" (junior, senior, etc.) and "business" (core, marketing, etc.). For every email address and most recent record (which I can identify with a "max date" filter), there is one and only one "level" and "business."

When I update the "email" parameter, I need the third view to filter for all users with the provided user's business and level.

If I were doing this in SQL, it would look like this for parameter value "myEmail":

`select avg(MyMetric) from table1 where table1.level=(select level from table1 where email="myEmail" limit 1) and table1.business=(select business from table1 where email="myEmail" limit1)`

I don't want to apply the "email" filter to the third view, but I need the "level" and "business" filters to be set automatically based on "email" - how can I accomplish this?

I'm sure this has been done, but haven't found a solution after several hours on SO and Tableau forums. This solution was close, since the second filter (city) depends on the first (state), but the first filter is still applied.

- [https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/making-filter-dependent#:~:text=How%20to%20make%20the%20values%20shown%20in%20a,on%20the%20value%20selected%20in%20the%20State%20filter](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/making-filter-dependent#:%7E:text=How%20to%20make%20the%20values%20shown%20in%20a,on%20the%20value%20selected%20in%20the%20State%20filter)

Thanks for the help - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to create a calculation that grabs the Level and Business for the selected email address, use an LOD to make these values available across the whole data source, and then compare them to each row. The calculation could look something like this:

```
{MIN(IF [Email] = [Email Parameter] THEN [Level] END)} = [Level] 
AND {MIN(IF [Email] = [Email Parameter] THEN [Business] END)} = [Business]
```

Add this to the filters shelf and select true to keep all emails that have the same Level and Business as the email selected in your parameter.